# PyQt strange behavior on clicked items

Tags: python, pyqt, signals

I have a table with multiple rows and on column 0 I put it a check-box, defined like this:

```
for char in accounts:
    for columnNumber in range(numberColumns):
        pWidget = QWidget()
        pCheckbox = QCheckBox()
        pLayout = QVBoxLayout(pWidget)
        pLayout.addWidget(pCheckbox)
        pLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        pLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0 ,0, 0)
        pCheckbox.setCheckState(False)
        pCheckbox.clicked.connect(self.handleItemClicked)
        pWidget.setLayout(pLayout)
        self.mainAccountTable.insertRow(currentRowCount)
        self.mainAccountTable.setCellWidget(currentRowCount, 0, pWidget)
        self.mainAccountTable.setItem(currentRowCount, 1, QTableWidgetItem(char[1]))
```

And I have a method connected for handling the clicks:

```
def handleItemClicked(self):
    try:
        #self.accountsSelected = []
        for account in range(self.mainAccountTable.rowCount()):
            if self.mainAccountTable.cellWidget(account, 0).findChild(type(QCheckBox())).isChecked():
                self.accountsSelected.add(self.mainAccountTable.item(account, 1).text())
                print ("yes:",self.accountsSelected)
            else:
                self.accountsSelected.remove(self.mainAccountTable.item(account, 1).text())
                print ("no:",self.accountsSelected)
    except Exception as e:
        print ("Error",e)
```

What bothers me is that is working perfect, but it's refreshing the results only if I check or uncheck the the first check-box (row 0, column 0). I tried also with connecting the signal with `toggled` ... same result. 
So, how can I make it to update the results when I check or uncheck others rows except the first one? Thanks in advance.

Later Edit:
I update it my code and the output is like this:
If I check other checkboxes except the first one this is the output:
`'Account1'`
and If I have selected, let's say 5 accounts and I have the first checkbox also selected this is the output:

```
    yes: {'Account2', 'Account1'}
    yes: {'Account2', 'Account1'}
    yes: {'Account2', 'Account1', 'Account3'}
    yes: {'Account2', 'Account1', 'Account3', 'Account4'}
    yes: {'Account2', 'Account1', 'Account3', 'Account4', 'Account5'}
    Error: 'Account 6' #is not selected which is true, BUT WHY is checking also for that?!?!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was in "else" branch and the work around is to have 2 for loops for each check:

```
def handleItemClicked(self, account):
    try:
        accountsSelected = set()

        for account in range(self.mainAccountTable.rowCount()):
            if self.mainAccountTable.cellWidget(account, 0).findChild(type(QCheckBox())).isChecked():
                accountsSelected.add(self.mainAccountTable.item(account, 1).text())                    
                print ("selected:",accountsSelected)
        for account in range(self.mainAccountTable.rowCount()):
            if not self.mainAccountTable.cellWidget(account, 0).findChild(type(QCheckBox())).isChecked():
                accountsSelected.remove(self.mainAccountTable.item(account, 1).text())
                print ("not selected:",accountsSelected)  

        print ("main:", accountsSelected)
        return accountsSelected
    except Exception as e:
        print ("error:",e)
```

Answer (score 0):

there are n = `rowCount()` pCheckBoxes.  but only the `clicked()`-signal of 1 pCheckBox is connected to `self.handleItemClicked()`.  Take the `connect()` in the first part of code, to connect every pCheckBox. As there are n pCheckboxes, pWidgets, pLayouts delete the 'self':

```
            pWidget = QWidget()
            pCheckbox = QCheckBox()
            pLayout = QVBoxLayout(pWidget)
            pLayout.addWidget(pCheckbox)
            pLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            pLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0 ,0, 0)
            pCheckbox.setCheckState(False)
            pCheckBox.clicked.connect(self.handleItemClicked)
            pWidget.setLayout(pLayout)
            self.mainAccountTable.insertRow(currentRowCount)
            self.mainAccountTable.setCellWidget(currentRowCount, 0, pWidget)
```

Comment: I updated my question. My connection was under the setting the cell, now is in front, but makes no difference.

Comment: I found a solution. I posted as an answer